# find and delete specific tags in an xml file

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep, find

I have the following xml structure:

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>FooServletFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>
    com.foo.web.online.util.csrf.FooServletFilter
 </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>FooServletFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/bar/foo/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Well, We had an emergency and need to remove these filters that are in production.

I was thinking I can `find` the web.xml files that contains these filters and remove them with `sed`

I am fine with `find` and `exec` but failed with `sed`.

`#find / -type f -name "web.xml -exec sed -i -e 's/<filter>.*FooServletFilter<\/filter>//g`

Failed. Then i wanted to try `sed` on my local file

I tried  many things like the following:

`sed -i -e 's/<filter>.*FooServletFilter<\/filter>//g' web.xml`

But no luck.

ps: i have multiple xml nodes. I need to remove the nodes that has
 `FooServletFilter`

Can you please help me out on this one?

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input. Your input makes it look like all you need is to remove the exact string `<filter-name>FooServletFilter</filter-name>` - if that isn't the case then provide more realistic sample input/output or you're going to end up with a solution to a problem you don't have. Show a case that'd be hard to handle, not the trivial sunny-day case. And the right solution will not involve sed so you should at least tag this with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command gets tricky with multiple lines.

This is a hacky solution to handle the `\n` line separators. (as suggested here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

Note that I am assuming you want the whole filter block removed. Tested with your input string above, but might need tweaking for multiple matches.

```
cat your.xml | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e 's/<filter>.*FooServletFilter.*<\/filter>//' | tr '\r' '\n' > your_new.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I got

```
gsed '/<filter>/ {:1; {/<\/filter>/!{N; b1;}; h;}; x; /FooServletFilter/!p; d; }' <your file>
```